# CSS - Div z-index being ignored

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a higher z-index than the div before, however, the div with the higher z-index is going behind the div before it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menu-button").click(function(){
    $("#menu").show(1000, function() {
      $("#option1").show(1500, function() {
        $("#option2").show(1500, function() {
          $("#option3").show(1500, function() {
            $(":not(#menu)").click(function(){
              $("#menu").hide(100);
            });
          });
        }); 
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
html, body{ height:100%; width:100%; padding:0; margin:0; overflow-x: hidden;}
#body{background:#333333; height: 100%; z-index:-5;}
#rotate{transform: rotate(5deg); background:#666; width:100%; height: 100%; position:absolute;}
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
.mobMenu{
  height:100%;
  width:35%;
  background:#006666;
}
.btn{
  background:#039;
}
.page{
  border:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  z-index:3;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <div id="rotate"></div>
  <div class="page">
    <span id="menu-button" style="color:#FFF;">TEST</span>
    <div class="mobMenu hidden" id="menu">
      <button class="hidden" id="option1">1</button>
      <button class="hidden" id="option2">2</button>
      <button class="hidden" id="option3">3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I would assume that the div "rotate" would be behind the div "page" however, this seems to not be the case.

I would like to use the rotated div as a background, and have it so that when the user scrolls it doesn't take remove the rotated box background.

(the script at the top is just in case, for any reason, that affects anything)

Comment: Remove the negative `z-index` on your body. Remove the `z-index` on your `.page`. Add negative `z-index` to your `#rotate`.

Comment: Add `position: relative;` to `.page`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [visual formatting model documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html), the `z-index` property [only applies to *positioned* elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#layers). In your case, the `.page` element has a default `position` value of `static`, which means that the `z-index` will not affect the element.

If you position the element, by changing the `position` value to `relative`/`absolute`/`fixed`, then it will work as expected.

```
.page {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative; /* Added. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp:

> z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute,
>   position:relative, or position:fixed).

Your `.page` isn't "positioned".

Also, you don't appear to have a `z-index` specifically set on `#rotate`. You might not need it, but I'd recommend giving it a `z-index` of 2 or lower.

Any reason you felt you needed a `z-index` of -5 on `#body`?

Comment: It was on -5 just for testing, and I forgot to remove it. And I did have #rotate with 2 to begin with, but felt it didn't need to be there

Comment: Yeah it should work fine without it, it's just for code maintainability reasons that I recommended it. When you come back to update your page in a month's time it'll help you to remember what the page is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the following CSS:

```
#body{background:#333333; height: 100%; }
#rotate{transform: rotate(5deg); background:#666; width:100%; height: 100%; position:absolute; z-index:1}
.page{
    position:relative;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:2;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Removed z-index from body, added z-index:1; to #rotate, changed .page z-index:2

https://jsfiddle.net/ogvopvxs/

Answer (score 0):

Just change the z-index of `#page` to 0 and `#rotate` to -1.

```
#rotate { z-index: -1; } 

#page { z-index: 0; }
```